# Difference between AMPscript and SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, ssjs

What is the main difference between AMPscript and SSJS in Marketing Cloud? Can you please give me clear information about the differences between AMPscript and SSJS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In everyday life, AMPScript is sufficient for most personalisation tasks, when it comes to emails and landing pages. SSJS offers a larger set of functions, which I mainly use for data integrations to external APIs.

Briefly speaking, AMPScript is for personalisation and SSJS for development/integrations. Here are some more points:

- AMPscript simply and efficiently handles inline personalization or simple IF ELSE statements.
- AMPscript better handles use cases, where each subscriber needs to see unique content, than SSJS.
- AMPscript has a shorter learning curve than SSJS for users new to scripting languages in general.
- A great deal of people already know JavaScript and can immediately apply that knowledge to Marketing Cloud
- In general, the vast majority of users can handle the tasks they need to perform using AMPscript. Use Core library SSJS functions only to accomplish tasks on landing pages where AMPscript does not provide appropriate functions. Platform SSJS functions can handle messaging tasks as well as landing pages and applications.

Answer (score 1):

ssjs:
Marketing Cloud executes the JavaScript on the server when rendering. Use Core server-side JavaScript functions to personalize landing pages and create applications to run on Marketing Cloud
Ampscript:
AMPscript is a scripting language that you can embed within HTML emails, text emails, landing pages

Comment: @A R 
Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: @Faheem test Welcome

Comment: This is not quite right - AMPScript also has the ability to handle API calls and manipulate Data Extension, etc.  It is actually the more recommended language to use in all aspects of SFMC. SSJS is generally slower processing and although a bit more robust, most of its 'extra' functions can be accomplished via SOAP/REST calls in AMPScript.  The best reason for using SSJS instead of AMPscript is JSON handling. (Albeit there are exceptions to the above - but they are specific use cases)